# How to create a pointer to pointer array to struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, delete-operator

I want to create a dynamic array of pointers that each one of them points to a struct. In the program there is an option to add structs and if the counter reaches the last the value of the array, the array expands.

```
struct student
{
    string id;
    string name;
};

int N=5;
int counter=0;
student **big=new student *[N]; //a ptr to an array of ptr's.

void add_student (int &counter,student **big)
{
    int i;

    if (counter==0)
    {
        for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            big[i]=new student; 
        }
    }

    if (counter==N)
    {
        N+=5;
        student **temp=new student *[N];
        for (i=counter-1; i<N; i++)
        {
            temp[i]=new student;
        }

        for (i=0; i<counter; i++)
        {
            temp[i]=big[i];
        }

        delete [] big;
        big=temp;
    }

    cout<<"Enter student ID: "<<endl;
    cin>>(*big)[counter].id;

    cout<<"Enter student name: "<<endl;
    cin>>(*big)[counter].name;

    counter++;
}
```

When I run the program it crashes after I try to add more than one student. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just step into your C++ boots, and use STL? This is why it has *containers*, to save you from having to re-implement this particular wheel.

Comment: As above, use a `std::vector` of `student` pointers, like so: `std::vector<student*>`, then just use `pushback` to add new pointers.

Comment: I keep on seeing C++ questions about wanting to use "dynamic arrays"... I'm guessing some coursework needs updating in some schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Main problem was that you write to `(*big)[counter].id` without this being valid memory. In my function below a student object is created first, then writen to.

PS: I have not tested the code, let me know if it has problems with it.

```
struct student {
  string id;
  string name;
};

int N=5;
int counter=0;
student **big = new student *[N]; //a ptr to an array of ptr's.

// Variable big and counter is global, no need to pass as argument.
void add_student (student *new_student) {
    // Resize if needed
    if (counter==N) {
        int i;

        student **temp=new student *[N+5];

        // Copy from the old array to the new
        for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
            temp[i]=big[i];
        }

        // Increase maximum size
        N+=5;

        // Delete the old
        delete [] big;
        big=temp;
    }

    // Add the new student
    big[counter] = new_student; 

    counter++;
}

// Function called when we should read a student
void read_student() {
    student *new_student = new student;

    cout<<"Enter student ID: "<<endl;
    cin>>new_student->id;

    cout<<"Enter student name: "<<endl;
    cin>>new_student->name;

    // Call the add function
    add_student (new_student);
}
```

Comment: When you say that a student object is created first. Where exactly in the code is it?

Comment: Its here: `student *new_student = new student;`. I allocate memory for a new student, then use cin<< to write to that new object.

Comment: It's working! so just to be clear about it. If I create a pointer to a pointer array to structs, I must create objects to write on them.

Comment: Yes. What `student **big = new student *[N];` does is only to allocate memory to hold N pointers. They don't point to any valid memory address initially.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried. the error is because you are not handling pointer to pointer to a struct correctly. to pass a pointer to pointer to something means the function can change the pointer address not only the thing it points to. so declaring a pointer to pointer in function is okay but declaring a global p to p to s doesn't make much sense. You can achieve the same effect using &ptr. for p to p to s i.e. pass the address of pointer to function. I made some changes but I'm not sure if it works. I will try again after 4/5 hours and will check the issue in detail. for the time being please content yourself with the following. (might be some errors below so be careful)

```
    struct student
    {
      string id;
      string name;
    };

    int N=5;
    int counter=0;
    student *big=new student[N]; //a ptr to an array of ptr's.

    void add_student (int &counter,student **ppBig)
    {
     int i;

    if (counter==0)
    {
     for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        *ppBig[i]=new student; 
    }

if (counter==N)
{
    N+=5;
    student *temp=new student [N];
    for (i=counter-1; i<N; i++)
        temp[i]=new student;

    for (i=0; i<counter; i++)
        temp[i]=*ppBig[i];

    delete[] *ppBig;
    ppBig=temp;
}


cout<<"Enter student ID: "<<endl;
cin>>(*big)[counter].id;

cout<<"Enter student name: "<<endl;
cin>>(*big)[counter].name;

counter++;
```

}